# A tag exists but it fades [magento-admin]

Tags: support, tags

I've been spending quite a bit of time tweaking my Magento e-commerce site and while asking a question, I noticed I couldn't use the [magento-admin] tag. I add it but then it fades out. The magento-admin email subscription is quite useful, as is the tag.

**Edit:** Here is an example: *[Magento Adminhtml override module not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948525)* I just edited it to add the [magento-admin] tag. It appeared in the pop-up below the tagbox. I click it, it adds to the list in the tagbox. I click save. Not there on the question afterwards. Also, in this case, [magento-admin] is different from [adminhtml], which implies custom module code for use in the back end.

Why does it do that? Is there a place on SE where I can read how tags work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[magento-admin](/questions/tagged/magento-admin) is [currently a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/magento/synonyms) of [magento](/questions/tagged/magento). Any attempt you make at adding that tag will automatically remap it to its master tag. The 325 questions you're seeing listed as having that tag already existed before the synonym was created and haven't yet been merged into the master tag.

> [image: also: magento-admin]

Comment: OK, that's it. So once the Magento SE is out of beta, questions can be migrated?

Comment: @ChrisK: We don't migrate questions just because another site opens up. We only migrate questions because they're *off-topic*.

Answer (score 0):

As well as what @animuson has said...

It would appear that flag had some sort of "tidy up" perhaps in some sort of preparation for https://magento.stackexchange.com/ ?

---

[magneto](/questions/tagged/magneto) has the following synonyms:

[magento-enterprise](/questions/tagged/magento-enterprise), [magento-extension](/questions/tagged/magento-extension), [magento-theming](/questions/tagged/magento-theming), [magento-catalog](/questions/tagged/magento-catalog), [magento-upgrade](/questions/tagged/magento-upgrade) and [magento-admin](/questions/tagged/magento-admin).

---

So it would appear that the "components" are all mapped to the main tag, and only version numbers are kept as auxiliary tags. Which may suggest that orphaned tags should be tidied up.

It's also strange that https://magento.stackexchange.com/ seems to have all the tags back for the different modules/components...

Maybe someone more familiar with [magneto](/questions/tagged/magneto) could explain the way the tag is supposed to work - there doesn't appear to be any help in the tag info/wiki... And although I'm not familiar with the system, I would have thought "theming" & "admin" etc... would be quite useful to be able to filter on.

Comment: Magento has its own SE?! ~head explodes~